# Solved: What does this sentence mean: Geometrically, a root of $(1)$ is that value of $~x~$ when the graph of $~f(x)~$ crosses the $~x$-axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Thanks Quasi for solving my question, what i really meant to ask is what the author means by root of (1) and the answer to that is that it is just a label for the equation and the same thing as say for a root of f(x).

This sentence is from the book Higher Engineering Mathematics by B.S. Grewal

[image]

What does this sentence mean: Geometrically, a root of $(1)$ is that value of $~x~$ when the graph of $~f(x)~$ crosses the $~x$-axis ?

Comment: It means the book is an  inferior text.  y = f(x) = x$^2$ = 0 is an example where the curve does not cross the x-axis.

Comment: yes as mentioned by Quasi the correct word would be intersect or in simple term touches the x-axis.

Comment: Theoretically, this statement is wrong. "Crossing the $x$-axis" implies a sign change in $f(x)$, but roots of multiplicity $2$ like in $f(x)=x^2$ are also roots, but without the "crossing", "crosses or touches the $x$-axis" would be more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $r\in\mathbb{R}$, then $r$ is a root of the equation $f(x)=0$

$\iff\;f(r)=0$

$\iff\;$the equation $y=f(x)$ is such that $y=0$ when $x=r$

$\iff\;$the point $(r,0)$ is a point on the graph of the equation $y=f(x)$

$\iff\;$the graph of the equation $y=f(x)$ intersects the $x$-axis at $x=r$

**Note:**

The author was a little careless when using the phrase "crosses the $x$-axis".

Correct that to "intersects the $x$-axis".

Comment: Thank you Quasi, I do understand what a root of an equation or f(x) is (as mentioned by you a value of x on which the curve intersects the x-axis) but what i do not understand is what the author means by root of (1), is root of (1) the same thing as root of equation or a root of f(x)?

Comment: Oh, the $(1)$ is just a label for the equation, nothing more.

Comment: okay thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: Do you remember @quasi when we could speculate about math without the thought police silencing us for being off topic?

Comment: @WIlliam Elliot: The good old (sci.math) days!

Answer (score 0):

Consider your $f$ as a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, so the **graph of $f$** is a subset of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then a root of $f$ is a point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$, and so the point $(x,f(x))=(x,0)$ **lies** on the $x$-axis in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thank you Minato for the answer but I am struggling to understand what your answer means as this is the first time i have heard of the plane R^2 what is that but i do understand the point you are conveying regarding the root being a point that intersects the x-axis.